# What is the best way to upload multiple files along with metadata?

Tags: javascript, multipartform-data

I need to upload N files, with some data attached to each file, like the name of the recipient of the file.

To do that, I have something like this:

```
let form = new FormData();
for (let file of file_list) {
  form.append('files', file);
  form.append('metadata', JSON.stringify(file.metadata));
}
```

I send that using a simple `axios` POST, and on the server side, I match each file with its metadata using the index of the file in the list.
It works but is not super reliable.

Is there a reliable way to upload a list of files along with attached metadata?

I'd rather avoid converting to base64 due to the size of the files which can already be pretty high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When appending a file you can use the third argument to set a filename.

By generating a unique name, you can relate it to your metadata.

```
 let uniqueId = 0;
 const metadata = {};
 for (let file of file_list) {
    uniqueId++;
    const fileName = `file-${uniqueId}.bin`;
    form.append('files', file, fileName);
    metadata[fileName] = file.metadata;
 }
 form.append('metadata', JSON.stringify(metadata));
```